# "Information about the undocumented function Internal`DiracGammaMatrix"

Tags: matrix, physics, undocumented

Searching for information on undocumented functions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/805/what-are-some-%5C%20useful-undocumented-mathematica-functions), I found that there are no references about the use of the undocumented function **Internal`DiracGammaMatrix**.

Does anyone in the community have any information on this?

I appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: The only thing I know is that there are 3 different bases; Majorana, chiral, and Dirac. For instance try ``MatrixForm /@Table[Internal`DiracGammaMatrix[k, "Basis" -> "Chiral"], {k, 4}]``. Likewise for the other two choices

Comment: Thanks, mate! Add your response and I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Since, it's not much of a response other than saying that $\Gamma$-matrices are implemented as such, I am going to wait a bit to check if others have more elaborate answers. Nice catch by the way. I wrote something small on the undocumented functions thread a while ago and completely forgot about this command

Comment: You're right, we must wait for a more elaborate answer. That function seems interesting to me, since it's more specialized.

Comment: Hey mate, I hope you're okay. I haven't seen any activity from you in the community lately.

Comment: All is well, how are you? Just a lot of things to do, so I mainly do some maintenance here :-)

Comment: All good, just pulling out a bunch of backlogs. Glad to know you're okay, mate :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $\Gamma$-matrices are built-in, albeit undocumented. This is the `` Internal`DiracGammaMatrix `` command.

The are 3 choices for the basis of the matrices, namely chiral, Dirac and Majorana. From the above choices, the chiral basis is the default.

```
Table[Internal`DiracGammaMatrix[k, "Basis" -> "Chiral"] // 
  MatrixForm, {k, 4}]
Table[Internal`DiracGammaMatrix[k] // MatrixForm, {k, 4}]
```

> [image: ch]

```
Table[Internal`DiracGammaMatrix[k, "Basis" -> "Dirac"] // 
  MatrixForm, {k, 4}]
```

> [image: dirac]

```
Table[Internal`DiracGammaMatrix[k, "Basis" -> "Majorana"] // 
  MatrixForm, {k, 4}]
```

> [image: majo]